# permission error in deployment

Tags: ssis

In SSIS,I had tried to deploy a package, which is for importing data from MySQL to SQL SErver 2008, at another server. When I tried to execute the Package from SQL Server, the deployment failed. The error was access permission denied for MySQL user. What is the solution for this ? should I have to set any permission ? I have installed MySQL data provider at the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have the username and password stored in the package using UserKey encryption.

When you deploy to SQL Server and run it, it's run as a different user, thus not being able to decrypt the passwords. You can either not save sensitive information, encrypt with password, and/or use a configuration file on your SQL Server that also contains the password in the connection string for your MySQL server.